# React Native- How to pass state from a component to it's parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm building a React Native Application and I'm coming across this issue im not sure how to resolve

In my screen, I have a switch that when pressed, invokes a function:

```
function RoundTrip(props) {
    console.log('value of round trip' + props.returnBool)
  var roundTrip = props.returnBool;
  if (roundTrip) {
       console.log('return is true')
    return <RoundTripTrue />;
  }
  console.log('return is false')
  return <RoundTripFalse />;

 }

function RoundTripFalse(props) {
  return  null
}

function RoundTripTrue(props) {
    return  (
        <View>
                        <CardSectionInput>


                    <Image
                        source={require('./../../src/images/dateIcon1.png')}
                        style={styles.IconStyle}
                    />
                    <DatePicker
                style={styles.DateStyle}
                date={this.state.returnDate}
                mode='date'

                format="LL"
                minDate= {currentDate}
                maxDate="2018-06-01"
                confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                showIcon={false}
                placeholder= 'Return Date'
                customStyles={{
                dateInput: {
                    marginLeft: 2,
                    backgroundColor: 'white', 
                    borderWidth: 1, 
                    borderRadius: 5, 
                    borderColor: 'white',
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                },
                dateText: {
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    flex: 1,  
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    color: 'black',
                },
                placeholderText: {
                    color: '#c9c9c9',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    fontSize: 18,

            }
                }}
                onDateChange={(returnDate) => {this.setState({returnDate: returnDate})}}
            />


        </CardSectionInput>


        <CardSectionInput>


                    <Image
                        source={require('./../../src/images/timeIcon.png')}
                        style={styles.TimeIconStyle}/>

            <DatePicker
                style={styles.DateStyle}
                date={this.state.returnTime}
                mode="time"
                format="LT"
                confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                minuteInterval={20}
                showIcon={false}
                placeholder='Return Time'
                onDateChange={(returnTime) => {this.setState({returnTime: returnTime});}}
                customStyles={{
                dateInput: {
                    marginLeft: 2,

                    backgroundColor: 'white', 
                    borderWidth: 1, 
                    borderRadius: 5, 
                    borderColor: 'white',
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',


                },
                dateText: {
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    flex: 1,  
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    color: 'black',

                },
                dateTouchBody: {
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    height: 40,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    flex: 1,
                    paddingTop: 5,

                },
            placeholderText: {
                    color: '#c9c9c9',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    fontSize: 18,

            }
                }}
                />

        </CardSectionInput>
```

This is working correctly, but my issue comes when I try to change my state of my RoundTrip function to my parent.

In my parent, I'm calling  `<RoundTrip returnBool={this.state.roundTrip} />`

I understand that my function doesnt have access to my parent's state, but I am lost on how to tackle this.

This problem is not specific to my RoundTrip function, as I am facing this problems whenever I try to separate  my files into components.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: so the issue is when you put these functions into different files? why not just `export` and then `import` it in a new file? also for getting back to the parent just pass a function `<RoundTrip onSelectionChange={this.handleChange} />` where handleChange is a function that takes some value and sets state.

Comment: Also, the examples you have here are called `Functional Components` as opposed to a `React Class`. Functional components dont have a state, and you cant call setstate in them. This should be throwing an exception. You need to make these react classes with state if you want to use state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to pass the Roundtrip component a callback function of the parent component via a property.

The Roundtrip component so can return values to the parent component.

```
<Roundtrip onChange={this.parentsMethodThatShallBeCalled} />
```

The parent's method could look like this:

```
function parentsMethodThatShallBeCalled(newValueFromRoundTrip) {
   this.setState({roundtrip : newValueFromRoundTrip});
```

}